# UML diagram Display framework

Tags: uml, visualization

I am looking to make a prototype of a UML differencing tool. What open source visualization tool kit exist that allow me to display UML diagrams?

Yet, I still need to be able to make personal edits the display. (Ie. refocusing, and drop down lists, additional displays.)

I have looked at [Zest](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest#New_layout_algorithms) and [Perfuse](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~amazeika/projects/prefuse/prefuse.html). But neither of these applications have a way to display a UML. If they do work, where are examples of them displaying UMLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to have a look at [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). As far as I know, [ArgoUML](http://argoeclipse.tigris.org/) is based on this framework.

Comment: I initially overlooked the front page of GEF.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source UML tools for Eclipse listed  [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility) along with their license.

For the diff part, you should check [EMFCompare](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/) and this list of [model versioning tools](http://modeling-languages.com/version-control-tools-modeling-artifacts/)  since they could be reused in your project

Comment: These are all prebuilt UML tools. But I am looking for a visualization tool kit. Prebuilt tools are hard to customize even if they are open source.